# looping an http server output

Tags: java, http, server

I have an example for a very basic HTTP server. when a user connects to the server the server outputs the time stamp.

```
public class SimpleFileServer {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(3030), 0);
   server.createContext("/time", new MyHandler());
   server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
   server.start();
 }

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
  public void handle(HttpExchange t){
     LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
     try {
       String response = ldt.toString();
       t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
       OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
       os.write(response.getBytes());
       os.close();    
     } catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println(ex);}  
  }
}}
```

is it possible to put the time stamp output in a loop ( a while loop or something like that) so that the time stamp would change every 1/5/10 seconds without the user refreshing the web page?

Eventually, I would like to send files out instead of the time stamp.

Thank you. any help would be appreciated

Comment: It is possible. I think what you're looking for is Ajax, to asynchronously make requests from your client side javascript env

Comment: do you think it will be better if the client would sent repeated requests to the server and will get a specific file in response instead of the server sending repeated files out?

Comment: i don't understand... btw it's always the client that send requests, then the server reply with whatever content. I would add also that is easier to send one file per time just because common web servers does support it

Comment: ok, thats what i was asking. so basically if the client sends request every 1 sec than it will get the file every 1 sec from the server? am i correct?

Comment: yes you are correct. of course if the file is 1GiB one second will be not enough to transmit it (probably)

Comment: the files are 1 kb. preaty small. back to my original question, is it posibble that when the client makes a request, instead of sending him one file, to create a stream of data (using a loop or something like that) and keep constantly pushing him the data?

Comment: yeah it's possible to do that. you need to write a script that will make your web server to act as you want in your favorite language (php for example). Just write a loop that open the files you want and write them to the http client.

Comment: @user2543740 in the code example above where would this loop be? can i place it inside the `try` and then read each file and place it int the `os.write()`? is that what you mean?